# How to resolve SQL State = 23503 Native Error Code = -530 in DB2?

Tags: sql, db2

My Application is executing insert query

```
insert into test.tab1
(NSALGNP,CCMOD,CMODTYP,CMODFTRYOPT,NFRMELVTH,NFRMSEQ,TCREATSTAMP,CPRF,CCIV,CSEX,NDLRBRN,NDLR,DPUR
,NEUSSTREET,XEUSFRTNAM,XEUSNAM,CLUPDUSER,TLUPDSTAMP,DBRTHDAY
,XSTREET2,XCITY,XCTRY,XPOST,XSTREET1,XTEL)
values
('217','WX10T','E1','','3','009389',current timestamp,'14','1','M','','999003','13.02.2021'
,'','ARMAND','JENNET','WINDEV',current timestamp,'01.01.0001'
,'','MOLAS','FR','31230','VILLAGE','');
```

Below is the error:

Description = [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2] SQL0530N  The insert or update value of the FOREIGN KEY "GFREU03" is not equal to any value of the parent key of the parent table.  SQLSTATE=23503

SQL State = 23503
Native Error Code = -530

Error code: 22
Level: fatal error (EL_FATAL)

Comment: your error says everything you need

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: In Db2, An empty-string (shown in your question as '' ) is different from a NULL, so if you want the foreign-key-column (s) to be empty use NULL not '' in your code when inserting foreign-key column values.  Separately if you want a not-null value in the foreign-key-column then a row must pre-exist in the parent table before you can refer to that row in your child table.

Comment: Never store empty strings, store NULL instead. Also, made up values like `'01.01.0001'` is also a bad idea - use NULL instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should have basic understanding of [Primary key, referential integrity, check, and unique constraints](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=concepts-primary-key-referential-integrity-check-unique-constraints).
Your application tries to violate the referential constraint "GFREU03" obviously.
The following statement may help you to understand, what is violated exactly.

```
SELECT 
  PK.TABSCHEMA, PK.TABNAME
, LISTAGG (PK.COLNAME, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PK.COLSEQ) AS COLS_PARENT
, LISTAGG (CK.COLNAME, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CK.COLSEQ) AS COLS_CHILD
FROM SYSCAT.REFERENCES R
JOIN SYSCAT.KEYCOLUSE CK ON CK.TABSCHEMA = R.TABSCHEMA AND CK.TABNAME = R.TABNAME AND CK.CONSTNAME = R.CONSTNAME 
JOIN SYSCAT.KEYCOLUSE PK ON PK.TABSCHEMA = R.REFTABSCHEMA AND PK.TABNAME = R.REFTABNAME AND PK.CONSTNAME = R.REFKEYNAME 
WHERE R.TABSCHEMA = 'TEST' AND R.TABNAME = 'TAB1'
    AND R.CONSTNAME = 'GFREU03'
    AND CK.COLSEQ = PK.COLSEQ
GROUP BY PK.TABSCHEMA, PK.TABNAME
;
```

`COLS_CHILD` is a list of columns (foreign key columns) in the table you tried to insert into.
`COLS_PARENT` is a list of columns (primary key columns) in the corresponding parent table `TABSCHEMA.TABNAME`.
A set of values in the foreign key columns you specified doesn't exist in the primary key columns of the parent table. This is why you get the error.

The solution is not to insert rows with values violating such a constraint.